# How to design the icon of a Modelica component?

Tags: modelica, dymola

Is there any software that allows designing the icon of a Modelica component, and then copy into Dymola?
It is hard to draw the picture in Dymola.

[image]

A short summary of the answers, there is 4 software support this task:

1. OMEdit;
2. MoVE;
3. InkSpace;
4. PowerPoint;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some tasks [OMEdit](https://www.openmodelica.org/) is better.  Properties of graphical elements are nicely presented in a single dialog and you can easily edit the points of lines and polygons.

[image]

As an alternative you can use svg and png files, which can be nicely drawn with [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is [MoVE](https://github.com/modelica-tools/MoVE), but it seems development is stopped.

Comment: MoVE only support MacOS, hope there would be an version that supports WinOS.

Comment: No, it is Java and I had it successfully running on my other Win machine.

Comment: Latest release of MoVE is https://github.com/THM-MoTE/MoVE/releases/tag/v0.7.1

Answer (score 1):

Another option for creating icons and info-graphics is to make them in standard packages for drawing, save them in a proper format (e.g., .png) and then use them. This is what I do with my library.

One way I have done it is with powerpoint and wrote a macro that auto-names them: https://github.com/ORNL-Modelica/TRANSFORM-Library/blob/master/TRANSFORM/Resources/Images/Icons.pptm

Next to that is another one for info slides.

Another one worth a go is something like Inkscape (https://inkscape.org/) and then you can run a command line terminal to loop through them all and generate png/jpgs.

Answer (score 1):

The following **platform-independent** method, i.e. works with arbitrary Modelica simulation environments, is particularly useful for sophisticated icons:

1. Use LibreOffice Draw for drawing an Icon
2. For each drawing, produce an image file in one of the desired format according to quality requirements
3. Include the image file within standard annotation for icons

Here is an example from the library [GenKinetics](https://github.com/AtiyahElsheikh/GenKinetics/tree/v1.0-alpha):

1. An Icon draw in *.gif format: [Inhibition Icon](https://github.com/AtiyahElsheikh/GenKinetics/blob/v1.0-alpha/Icons/modifierconnection_I2.gif)
2. A component employing the Icon: [Port_I.mo](https://github.com/AtiyahElsheikh/GenKinetics/blob/v1.0-alpha/Icons/Port_I.mo)